# Custom metabox content displayed in single product additional tabs on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, meta-boxes

Thanks to these two posts I have come up with this solution for adding multiple tabs to Woocommerce product detail page.

[Editing Custom product tab content in Woocommerce Admin product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993087/editing-custom-product-tab-content-in-woocommerce-admin-product-pages)

[Adding multiple tabs to WooCommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964939/adding-multiple-tabs-to-woocommerce-single-product-pages)

However, I am still having trouble saving the data and can't figure out how to make each meta_box save. I thought of a foreach statement but I'm not that well versed in PHP to know how the syntax is.

Here is my code. I have 6 tabs I added which show up on the page, and the meta boxes show up in the admin panel but they won't save any input. I only have one that is trying to save right now and I feel like the problem is in the save function.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'create_custom_meta_box' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'create_custom_meta_box' ) )
{
    function create_custom_meta_box()
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_cost_field',
            __( 'Cost and Performance Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_environment_field',
            __( 'Environment Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_dilution_field',
            __( 'Dilution Directions Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_packaging_field',
            __( 'Packaging and Handling', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_application_field',
            __( 'Use and Application Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_product_specification_field',
            __( 'Product Specification Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
            'add_custom_content_meta_box',
            'product',
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}

//  Custom metabox content in admin product pages
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_custom_content_meta_box' ) )
{
    function add_custom_content_meta_box( $post )
    {
        $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cost_performance_tab', true ) ? get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cost_performance_tab', true ) : '';
        wp_editor( $value, 'custom_cost_performance_tab', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_product_field_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';

    }
}


//Save the data of the Meta field
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_content_meta_box', 10, 1 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'save_custom_content_meta_box' ) )
{

    function save_custom_content_meta_box( $post_id ) {

        // We need to verify this with the proper authorization (security stuff).

        // Check if our nonce is set.
        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'custom_product_field_nonce' ] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $nonce = $_REQUEST[ 'custom_product_field_nonce' ];

        //Verify that the nonce is valid.
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        // Check the user's permissions.
        if ( 'page' == $_POST[ 'post_type' ] ) {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } else {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }
        // --- Its safe for us to save the data ! --- //

        // Sanitize user input  and update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'cost_performance_tab', wp_kses_post($_POST[ 'custom_cost_performance_tab' ]) );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // 1) Removing tabs

    unset( $tabs['description'] );              // Remove the description tab
    // unset( $tabs['reviews'] );               // Remove the reviews tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab


    // 2 Adding new tabs and set the right order

    //Attribute Cost and Performance tab
    $tabs['cost_performance_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Cost + Performance', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 100,
        'callback'  => 'woo_cost_performance_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the environment tab
    $tabs['environment_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Environment', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 110,
        'callback'  => 'woo_environment_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the dilution tab
    $tabs['dilution_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Suggested Dilution Directions', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'woo_dilution_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the packaging tab
    $tabs['packaging_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Packaging + Handling', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'woo_packaging_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the application tab
    $tabs['application_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Use + Application', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'woo_application_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the application tab
    $tabs['specification_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Product Specification', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'woo_specification_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}

function woo_cost_performance_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cost_performance_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}

function woo_environment_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'environment_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}

function woo_dilution_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dilution_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}

function woo_packaging_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'packaging_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}

function woo_application_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'application_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}

function woo_specification_tab_content()  {
    // The new tab content
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();
    echo'<div><p>'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'specification_tab' ,true ).'</p></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 6 metaboxes in admin product edit pages and there is a lot of mistakes… Try the following instead:

```
// Add a custom metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'additional_product_tabs_metabox' );
function additional_product_tabs_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'add_product_metabox_additional_tabs',
        __( 'Additional product Tabs', 'woocommerce' ),
        'additional_product_tabs_metabox_content',
        'product',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

//  Add custom metabox content
function additional_product_tabs_metabox_content( $post )
{
    // Cost and Performance
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Cost and Performance', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cost_performance', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_cost_performance', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );

    // Environment
    echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Environment', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_environment', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_environment', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


    // Dilution Directions
    echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Dilution Directions', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dilution_directions', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_dilution_directions', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


    // Environment
    echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Packaging and Handling', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_packaging_and_handling', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_packaging_and_handling', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


    // Use and Application
    echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Use and Application', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_use_and_application', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_use_and_application', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


    // Environment
    echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_specification', true );
    wp_editor( $value, '_specification', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


    // Nonce field (for security)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="additional_product_tabs_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
}


// Save product data
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'save_additional_product_tabs', 10, 1 );
function save_additional_product_tabs( $post_id ) {

    // Security check
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'additional_product_tabs_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    //Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'additional_product_tabs_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Sanitize user input and save the post meta fields values.

    if( isset($_POST[ '_cost_performance' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cost_performance', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_cost_performance' ]) );

    if( isset($_POST[ '_environment' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_environment', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_environment' ]) );

    if( isset($_POST[ '_dilution_directions' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_dilution_directions', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_dilution_directions' ]) );

    if( isset($_POST[ '_packaging_and_handling' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_packaging_and_handling', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_packaging_and_handling' ]) );

    if( isset($_POST[ '_use_and_application' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_use_and_application', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_use_and_application' ]) );

    if( isset($_POST[ '_specification' ]) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_specification', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_specification' ]) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // 1) Removing tabs

    unset( $tabs['description'] );              // Remove the description tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab

    // 2 Adding new tabs and set the right order

    //Attribute Cost and Performance tab
    $tabs['cost_performance_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Cost + Performance', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 10,
        'callback'  => 'woo_cost_performance_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the environment tab
    $tabs['environment_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Environment', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 20,
        'callback'  => 'woo_environment_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the dilution tab
    $tabs['dilution_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Suggested Dilution Directions', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 30,
        'callback'  => 'woo_dilution_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the packaging tab
    $tabs['packaging_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Packaging + Handling', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 40,
        'callback'  => 'woo_packaging_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the application tab
    $tabs['application_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Use + Application', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 60,
        'callback'  => 'woo_application_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the specification tab
    $tabs['specification_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Specification', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 70,
        'callback'  => 'woo_specification_tab_content'
    );

    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 80;

    return $tabs;
}


function woo_cost_performance_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_cost_performance' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_environment_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_environment' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_dilution_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_dilution_directions' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_packaging_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_packaging_and_handling' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_application_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_use_and_application' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_specification_tab_content()  {
    global $product;

    echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_specification' ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.